# how to compare values of pandas dataframe column with variable to get the sume when both the values are same?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to compare the value of variable with the values in column of pandas dataframe and  want to calculate the sum when both the values are same.

i tried the compare method that we usually use and .sum() function of pandas to get sum

```
dayofwk = 4
df = df_myinput['day_of_week']
abc=  df[(df == dayofwk)].sum()
print(abc)
```

eg
if df is {0.4.5.6.7.3.8.9.2.5.4.6.4.7.9}

then abc must show output as 12

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here??

Comment: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:1649: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)     and output is 0

Comment: @Joe tried after upgrading my pandas version but still its showing same result and the warning

Comment: @joe can you tell me the exact version of your python? i will downgrade to that version to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:
It worked for me.

```
abc=df[(df['day_of_week'].values==dayofwk)].sum()
```

Thanks.